# Makefile error :make: *** [main] Error 1

Tags: c++, makefile

I am executing a makefile with 3 parts for my project is about overloading opertions for big numbers:
BigNum.h

```
#include <vector>
#ifndef BIGNUM_H
#define BIGNUM_H
class impossible_number_exception{};
class BigNum{
public:
//some functions
private:
   //
};
#endif
```

the second part is BigNum.cpp that I include libraries and functions and the third part is main.cpp that I write it for testing my library:

```
int main(){
BigNum f("8913.67811");
BigNum r(-5453.578);
d=-1.02+f;
if(d>r){
cout<<f<<endl;
}
cout<<d[3];
return 0;
}
```

and my makefile is this:

```
all:main.o BigNum.o
   g++ -o a.out BigNum.o
main.o:main.cpp BigNum.o
   g++ -c main.cpp
BigNum.o:BigNum.h BigNum.cpp
   g++ -c BigNum.cpp
clean:
   rm -rf*.o
```

and I place all the tabs and spaces correctly but I got this error that some of its line is:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
cc   main.o   -o main
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference   std::allocator<char>::allocator()
...
main.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `BigNum::BigNum(double)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d9): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
main.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

what should I do about this?

Comment: You are not including BigNum.h in your main.cpp file.

Comment: no I include that:)))))))

Comment: What happens when you type `g++ -c main.cpp` in the terminal?

Comment: Do you have a constructor that looks like `BigNum(double num)`

Comment: I type  g++ .... but nothing happens

Comment: yes i have that constructor

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve] I think. It sounds like you might have a compiler error, and we cannot diagnose it without accurate code. (Remember "minimal")

Comment: What is "d"?: Type, where is it declared? Could you please provide the complete main?

Comment: thanks the problem seems to be about makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well now I change my makefile to this

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g
main: main.o BigNum.o
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o main main.o BigNum.o
main.o: main.cpp BigNum.h
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp
BigNum.o:BigNum.cpp BigNum.h
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c bignum.cpp
```

and it  works!!!!!!!!
but I can not found out about the problem of my first makefile!